# Sharepoint use metadata for column aim to searching but not work in Search This Site

Tags: search, search-results, document, metadata

Since users said that they want to more accurately search the documents, i try to create a new column and use metadata in it In Document Library.

However, i successfully can search the keyword in Document Library (find an item box), i try to search same keyword in (Box search This Site) but there are no any results in it.

The case seem to can search in find an item, but cannot search in search this site

any idea?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check for alternate access mapping default configuration. Crawl address should be same  is as default text box and start crawl address in search service application.

Try Changing address to : http://mycompany.com instead of http://server:port

Comment: Sorry, can i ask what mean the default text box? And i check the AAM also is using domain address (http://mycompany.com)